# Activity not being called

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a function calling an activity, but the activity is not called and instead, the MainActivity is called.  From what I can see there is nothing unusual about the call.  I can follow the intent all the way through the source code of activity, and I see the intent is the desired activity.

I create the intent:

```
Intent startNewActivityOpen2 = new Intent(this, com.assistek.ediary.TransitionLandscape.class);
setExtrasStartActivity(startNewActivityOpen2, extras);
```

Here is the method I call:

```
protected void setExtrasStartActivity(Intent i, Bundle extras) {
    // copy over all extras
    if (extras != null) {
        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            i.putExtras(extras);
        }
    }

    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    //I can see here that the the intent is correct
    startActivity(i);
    finish();

}
```

Logcat:

> 12-10 19:09:56.041 2857-2857/com.assistek.ediary D/Base Activity: **********Pause class com.assistek.ediary.TransitionLandscape
>       **********Pause Navigate: true
>       **********Resume class com.assistek.ediary.TransitionLandscape
>       **********Pause class com.assistek.ediary.TransitionLandscape
>       **********Pause Navigate: false
>   12-10 19:09:56.061 539-9188/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.assistek.util.homelauncher/.HomeLauncherActivity} from pid 0
>   12-10 19:09:56.181 2857-2857/com.assistek.ediary D/Base Activity: **********Focus: false Activity: class com.assistek.ediary.TransitionLandscape
>   12-10 19:09:56.191 1002-1006/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 479K, 12% free 7739K/8708K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 34ms
>   12-10 19:09:56.191 539-22740/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.assistek.ediary cmp=com.assistek.ediary/.Home} from pid 1002
>   12-10 20:19:49.371 1002-1006/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 842K, 11% free 7767K/8708K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 48ms
>   12-10 20:19:49.501 539-620/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 241K, 19% free 16643K/20352K, paused 58ms, total 59ms
>   12-10 20:19:49.501 539-620/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 16.531MB for 251120-byte allocation
>   12-10 20:19:49.561 539-620/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 19% free 16884K/20600K, paused 56ms, total 56ms
>   12-10 20:19:49.621 539-620/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 262K, 20% free 16621K/20600K, paused 58ms, total 58ms
>   12-10 20:19:49.621 539-27162/? I/ActivityManager: moveTaskToBack: 5106
>   12-10 20:19:49.641 539-22745/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.assistek.util.homelauncher/.HomeLauncherActivity} from pid 0
>   12-10 20:19:49.661 6240-6240/com.assistek.ediary D/Base Activity: **********Stop Navigate Away false

Why is the Home Launcher getting called?

EDIT:  If I call another activity, the correct activity displays.

EDIT: Here is my manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".TransitionLandscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
    </activity>
```

Comment: have you tried removing the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP ?

Comment: @Anonymous yes, same result

Comment: @KristyWelsh show us your manifest declaration?

Comment: @Hades here is my manifest declaration in the edited post.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "but the activity is not called and instead, the MainActivity is called." @KristyWelsh

Answer (score 0):

Is `com.assistek.ediary` your app's package name?

Looks like you are trying to call other app's activity which has HomeActivity as their launcher activity so its therefore Home activity is called.

```
 Intent secondActivityIntent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);              
 intent.putExtra("myKey", "MyValue");
 context.startActivity(secondActivityIntent);
```

Comment: Kall   Yes, come.assistek.ediary is my app's package name.  so use application context and that will solve things?

Answer (score 0):

I not a 100% sure if this is the right answer but it's worth a try,

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.assistek.ediary.TransitionLandscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and also make sure that you are overriding this and not anything else,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}
```

Comment: No, this did not work.  But thank you for your answer.